# How to send invoice in pdf attachment to customer via email usign stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments, cakephp-3.0

I want to send invoice in pdf format to the customer via email using stripe API.

I can fetch invoice and make custom html. But I want direct fetch pdf via stripe API. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear this is something Stripe offers.

https://stripe.com/docs/receipts

For most custom applications I tend to disable my payment gateway receipts and create my own. The disadvantage here is you have to have a authoritative transactional email service so things do not get sent to spam.

The advantage is you can customize the receipt to your liking and if you switch or add more payment gateways in the future, you do not have to recreate or handle multiple receipt emails.

**I would send the receipt from your app**

- Use a good transactional email service like SparkPost. They have a free tier and a great SMTP connection option that plugs into Cake's email class
- Make sure you have a DKIM signature setup and a valid SPF record. https://www.mail-tester.com/ is great for finding problems in emails